# Trying To Insert Key/value Pairs To The Request Body With Postman

Tags: postman

I am trying to insert key/value pairs to the request body in Postman, but I cannot do it! I click/double-click the body area, but nothing seems to happen.

I am stuck at this screen:
[image]

How can I add another JSON entry manually?

Comment: Did you try the "raw" tab?

Comment: I did actually. Still does not allow the option to edit the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screen shot, looks like you are trying to edit **Response** body rather than the **Request** body.
Postman only allows editing request body (which is logical).

If you want to use this response body contents in other request, copy and paste it in other request body and then edit it.

Comment: I should also mention that after restart, I was able to add key-value pairs using Postman.